# Cannot stream live data from websocket fyers

Tags: c#, websocket, stream

I'm currently working on a project that involves real-time data analysis, and I've successfully subscribed but cannot stream the data.

```
 while (true)
 {
    
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
     string receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
     Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {receivedMessage}");
 }
 Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket State: {ws.State}");
```

}

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXwLQ.png)